# What does the "cat" command in Powershell mean?

Tags: powershell, cat

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -C "get-process >> $env:APPDATA\test.log; cat $env:APPDATA\test.log"
```

Hi everyone, can someone translate what `cat` is in powershell? or if you're extra nice tell me what the whole script is saying?
I ran it in my VM but I'm still not understanding it.

Comment: `cat` is a synonym for the `Get-Content` command, which simply reads the content of document referenced by the passed parameter and outputs to the standard output the contents of it.

Comment: The way I found that `cat` is a synonym for `Get-Content` was by executing `help cat` in the console.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PowerShell has rich reflection capabilities.

To learn what a given command refers to, use the [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) cmdlet:

```sh
# On *Windows*
PS> Get-Command cat

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                                                           
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                                                           
Alias           cat -> Get-Content
```

This tells you that `cat` is an [*alias*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases) for the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) cmdlet.

```sh
# On *Unix*-like platforms (macOS, Linux)
PS> Get-Command cat

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     cat                                                0.0.0.0    /bin/cat
```

This tells you that `cat` refers to the *external program* (application) located at `/bin/cat` (the standard `cat` Unix utility).

Answer (score 0):

```
PS> Get-Alias cat

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                                                       
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                                                       
Alias           cat -> Get-Content
```

It is an alias to Get-Content command in powershell

Comment: Using `Get-Alias` rather than the more generic `Get-Command` presumes that that `cat` is an _alias_ - which isn't true on Unix-like platforms. In other words: If you want to know what command a given name refers to - whatever command _form_ it comes in - use `Get-Command`.